# How to define an angular-meteor controller?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

In [this tutorial](http://ng-meteor.meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/3-way-data-binding), the controller is:

```
angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl', function ($scope, $meteor) {
  $scope.parties = $meteor.collection(Parties);
});
```

In [another tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/collections), the controller is:

```
angular.module('simple-todos').controller('TodosListCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor',
  function ($scope, $meteor) {

  $scope.tasks = $meteor.collection(Tasks);
}]);
```

Are the above identical?

Answer (score 1):

It are two different notations. Both will work.

The second example uses "annotation" and is used when you are going to compress/uglify the code. Compressing your code will replace your service names and would break your code. Since the strings will not be replaced by the urligfier, Angular can use this to figure out what dependancies to inject.

Check out the Dependency Annotation part on this link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

If you use a taskmanager to minify your code, there are ways to have this done for you. An example can be found here: https://github.com/mzgol/grunt-ng-annotate